# How can I click a link but not reload the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an ordering system that everytime you click the up or down arrow it adds 1 or removes 1 from the order of the list.  Each time the link is clicked the page refreshes.

is there a way to avoid the refresh but still update and show the new order on the page?

My list

```
<div class="row select-order">
    <ol>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <li>                    
                    @item.TaskName
                    @if (item.TaskType != (short)OBTaskTypes.SignOn && item.TaskType != (short)OBTaskTypes.Finalize)
                    {

                        <a href="@Url.Action("SetTaskOrder", "OBClientSetupTasks", new { id = item.SetupID, tid = item.TaskID, oldOrder = (short)item.TaskOrder, newOrder = ((short)item.TaskOrder + 1)})"><i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i></a>
                        <a href="@Url.Action("SetTaskOrder", "OBClientSetupTasks", new { id = item.SetupID, tid = item.TaskID, oldOrder = (short)item.TaskOrder, newOrder = ((short)item.TaskOrder - 1) })"><i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i></a>
                    }                    
            </li>
        }
    </ol>
</div>
```

Each time one of those href's is clicked it sets the order and refreshes.

Comment: try <a herf="yourLink" onClick="return false;">text</a>

Comment: Technically, if those links aren't actually *links* then you shouldn't be using anchor tags in the first place.  Use just about any other text-based clickable element and style accordingly.  But since you're using an anchor, the browser is treating it like an anchor.  You *can* override that behavior, but you can also not use it in the first place.

Comment: Well when you click them they do exactly what they need to do. They run through the controller, set the order then postback.  I kind of think there isn't a way to display the updated order without refreshing.

Answer (score 2):

I would really look at it one more time and be sure that you need use an anchor tag for this. Maybe a button would be better. If it has to be, then you have to prevent the default event from happening.

http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault

```
$('.select-order a').click(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  // Do other stuff if needed
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/wxddszct

Comment: I tried this. The problem I ran into was it didn't update the order on the page after clicking.

Comment: It looks like what ever "ordering system" you are using, requires this refresh to perform the action.

PreventDefault does exactly what it says. it prevents the default from happening, in the case of a link it will stop it from "going" to that link (running through your controller). Maybe look into see if this can be done with an ajax call, that will not need to refresh the page.